# solana - how to get nft transfer history by wallet address?

Tags: solana

I want to get the history of someone sending NFTs to my wallet and from my wallet to another wallet. Is there any API ?

I tried using `getSignaturesForAddress` from `@solana/web3.js`, but the NFT Transfer does not remain.

like solana explorer's token history

> https://explorer.solana.com/address/Hhnij5YTq9oSE9EmXd8zM6L5CZboLpmmowRaeGtmm9b7/tokens?cluster=devnet

Answer (score 0):

I am using python for getting NFTs

First call `signatures = http_client.get_signatures_for_address(account)`
then call `response = http_client.get_transaction(signature)` for each signature from previous call. You will find below data in response:

```
metadata_id = response["result"]["transaction"]["message"]["instructions"][2]["accounts"][0]
metadata_address = response["result"]["transaction"]["message"]["accountKeys"][metadata_id]
```

last you can call `response= http_client.get_account_info(metadata_address )` for getting metadata from response look at `raw_metadata = response["result"]["value"]["data"][0]` you need to base58 encode for getting your metadata from this value.